# Searching users with taxonomy terms with search module

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, search

I have search set up with display suite to search user profiles and it works great for titles, bodies.  However I have taxonomy terms attached to the profiles but when I put the taxonomy term in the search nothing comes up.

I understand that search by taxonomy can be done by views exposed filters, and I have that implemented for one area of the site already.

What I need is for searching a taxonomy term in the default search bar to show users that have that taxonomy term on their profile.  I DO NOT want to have a separate search field with a view just to search by taxonomy term.

Is there a way to do this with search-api?  If so what sort of configuration must I do to get this to work?

Comment: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/8127/views-search-to-find-users-based-on-terms?rq=1

Comment: @blackem thanks for pointing me in the right direction